# Default case doesn't get executed c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have this function that checks whether a date is within range.

```
bool check_date(const int &in_day, const int &in_month, const int &in_year)
{
    if (in_year < 1582)
        return false;
    else if (in_year == 1582 && in_month < october)
        return false;
    else if (in_month < 1 || in_month > 12)
        return false;

    switch (in_month)
    {
    case january:       // 31 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
            return false;
        break;

    case february:      // 28 days, 29 if leap.
        if (is_leap(in_year))
        {
            if (in_day > 29 || in_day < 1)
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (in_day > 28 || in_day < 1)
                return false;
        }

    case march:         // 31 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
            return false;
        break;

    case april:         // 30 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
            return false;
        break;

    case may:           // 31 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
            return false;
        break;

    case june:          // 30 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
            return false;
        break;

    case july:          // 31 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
            return false;
        break;

    case august:        // 31 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
            return false;
        break;

    case september:     // 30 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
            return false;
        break;

    case october:       // 31 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
            return false;
        break;

    case november:      // 30 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
            return false;
        break;

    case december:      // 31 days
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
            return false;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout <<"CORRECT DATE";
    }

    return true;

}
```

While the code works as in it returns true and false where it should, the `default:` case never gets selected, even when the date is correct, for example where `in_day = 17, in_month = 9, in_year = 1999`. At first I had `return true;` inside the default case, but it would never return true, and after running the debugger I found that the default case never ran, so I moved `return` out of the switch statement (it works there). Am I doing something wrong, why doesn't the default case execute?

Comment: Where are `january`, `february`, etc. defined?

Comment: Where are `january, february` etc defined ?

Comment: You should compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Your fix-my-code question is off-topic here.

Comment: By my assumption, `in_month=9` will trigger the `case`  for september

Comment: Where's the `break` for february? In order for the default to be hit you'd need to have in_month be none of your other values which you seem to protect against at the beginning of the function. I'm not sure you understand how default works.

Comment: You'd save yourself a lot of duplication if you stacked your matching cases up like this: https://pastebin.com/uB0kNq7i

Comment: It's been quite a while since I last used a switch and I was thinking in terms of if-else if statements, where the last else is always executed if the other possibilities aren't used. Retired Ninja, thank you.

Comment: For the `default` case, change the output statement to be `std::cout << "INCORRECT DATE"`.  You are mistaken in believing that the default case will be employed if any others are.  The default case will only be executed if the other cases are not, since they all - particularly the last - are terminated with a `break` (except february, which means that the code for march is also executed for february, which is presumably incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **unreachable code**.
The `default` inside `switch (in_month)` is equal to

```
if (in_month < 1 || in_month > 12) return false;
```

So if you want to use `default` inside `switch (in_month)` you don't need `if (in_month < 1 || in_month > 12)` see:

```
  switch (in_month) {
  default: // if (in_month < 1 || in_month > 12)
    std::cout << "BAD month: ";
    return false;
```

see this **optimized** and cleaned code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum {
  january = 1,
  february,
  march,
  april,
  may,
  june,
  july,
  august,
  september,
  october,
  november,
  december
};
bool is_leap(const int year) {
  if (year % 400 == 0)
    return true;
  if (year % 100 == 0)
    return false;
  if (year % 4 == 0)
    return true;
  return false;
}
bool check_date(const int in_day, const int in_month, const int in_year) {
  if (in_year < 1582)
    return false;
  if (in_year == 1582 && in_month < october)
    return false;

  switch (in_month) {
  default: // if (in_month < 1 || in_month > 12)
    std::cout << "BAD DATE: ";
    return false;

  case january: // 31 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
      return false;
    break;

  case february: // 28 days, 29 if leap.
    if (is_leap(in_year)) {
      if (in_day > 29 || in_day < 1)
        return false;
    } else {
      if (in_day > 28 || in_day < 1)
        return false;
    }
    break;

  case march: // 31 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
      return false;
    break;

  case april: // 30 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
      return false;
    break;

  case may: // 31 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
      return false;
    break;

  case june: // 30 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
      return false;
    break;

  case july: // 31 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
      return false;
    break;

  case august: // 31 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
      return false;
    break;

  case september: // 30 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
      return false;
    break;

  case october: // 31 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
      return false;
    break;

  case november: // 30 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
      return false;
    break;

  case december: // 31 days
    if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
      return false;
    break;
  }
  std::cout << " CORRECT DATE: ";
  return true;
}
int main() {
  cout << check_date(0, 0, 2017) << endl;  // 0
  cout << check_date(29, 2, 2000) << endl; // 1
  cout << check_date(29, 2, 2017) << endl; // 0
  cout << check_date(1, 1, 2017) << endl;
  cout << check_date(1, 1, 2017) << endl;
  cout << check_date(1, 1, 2017) << endl;
}
```

output:

```
BAD month: 0
 CORRECT DATE: 1
0
 CORRECT DATE: 1
 CORRECT DATE: 1
 CORRECT DATE: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

default would be executed if you pass anything except january-dec
Since you test the range before the switch - you never enter the default case.

What you need to do - is take your

```
std::cout <<"CORRECT DATE";
```

out of the switch and put it before return true; - you will get there from any case when your test is passed and you did not return false - instead - going to break branch.